# Best time to save persistent data in Service (Service.onDestroy not always called)

Tags: java, android

I am working on a small financial app with an activity and a background service to update data periodically. I use AlarmManager + PendingIntent to update the data periodically in the background even if after the activity has been destroyed. When the service is running by itself in the background, it will be killed by the system from time to time but will be restarted automatically by the system in a short while since I return START_STICKY in onStartCommand.

Here is the problem. I put the code to save persistent data inside Service.onDestroy(). However, when the system kills my service out of its free will, Service.onDestroy() is not called. Where else should I save my data, then? I could save the data upon every data modification operation. But that seems pretty wasteful of CPU and I/O operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where else should I save my data, then?

Asynchronously, when the data changes.

> I could save the data upon every data modification operation. But that seems pretty wasteful of CPU and I/O operation.

Then your problem lies with your use of `AlarmManager`. If you are worried about the costs of doing the work, then do not do the work quite so frequently, or let the user control how frequently the work gets done.

Data held in a `Service`, like data held in static data members, is merely a cache, and should be treated as such.

Comment: The user does have the option to control the frequency. It might be set to a few seconds or an hour. We can't control users' behavior. However, as an operating system, it doesn't seem reasonable to kill a service without any sort of notification or callback.

Comment: @StephenCheng: "it doesn't seem reasonable to kill a service without any sort of notification or callback" -- you are welcome to your opinion. That does not change the fact that Android may not call `onDestroy()` on your service. That will either be in a case of high-priority RAM requirements (e.g., incoming phone call), the user force-stopping your app, or your service having an unhandled exception. *Normally* `onDestroy()` is called. However, data persistence should be more reliable than simple "normally".

Comment: There is no incoming call. I didn't force stop either. I just turn off the phone screen and let it go to sleep. In a few seconds, my service is terminated. But it is restarted by system very soon after that.

Comment: @StephenCheng: Then either you are using `bindService()` instead of `startService()`, or you are calling `stopService()`/`stopSelf()` somewhere in your code, or your device manufacturer is misbehaving. Also, please bear in mind that the CPU shuts down when the device goes to sleep. This does not terminate your process or stop your service, but it does suspend all current operations, much like a "suspend" mode does on a desktop OS.

Comment: @StephenCheng: And, bear in mind that the `bindService()` and `stopService()` scenarios from my preceding comment will trigger `onDestroy()` to be called. My first comment was citing cases where your service might not have `onDestroy()` be called. And, since those cases exist (whether or not they are part of your current testing regimen), you cannot rely upon `onDestroy()` to be called, and you need to persist your data changes when the changes occur.